# error get_result al hacer consulta

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para traer un solo dato, pero según la consulta no me arroja ningún resultado, me indica que es nulo , pero creo que tengo algo mal con get_result, agradezco cualquier comentario, saludos

Notice: Undefined index: Medida in C:\xampp\htdocs\medidas\insertar.php on line 36

este es mi código:

```
$idVariedad = "ALIBABA";

$sqlMedida = $conexion->prepare("Select Medida from siat.medida where Variedad = :Variedad;");
$sqlMedida->bindParam(':Variedad',$idVariedad,PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
$sqlMedida->execute();
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo $valor['Medida'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo en tu código es que usas un *fetch_style* aquí:

```
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Pero luego, la forma de leer el resultado **no es acorde con ese *fetch style***.

```
echo $valor['Medida'];
```

Si revisas [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), el *fetch style* que tú usas, que es `PDO::FETCH_NUM`:

> `PDO::FETCH_NUM`: devuelve un array indexado por el número de columna
> tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados, comenzando por la
> columna 0.

Significa que si haces esto:

```
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

La forma de lectura debe ser así:

```
echo $valor[0];
```

Tú estabas usando la forma de lectura propia de `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, la cual, según la documentación:

> `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las
> columnas del conjunto de resultados.

Por tanto, esto funcionaría sin problema:

```
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $valor['Medida'];
```

Para este caso, tú puedes usar también [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) el cual:

> Devuelve una única columna de la siguiente fila de un conjunto de
> resultados.

Por ejemplo:

```
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetchColumn();
echo $valor;
```

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro lo estas poniendo como un entero debería quedar como string

```php
$sqlMedida->bindParam("s",$idVariedad);
```

y al obtener el resultado debes usar la variable con la que se esta haciendo todo

```php
$valor = $sqlMedida->get_result();`
```

Comment: David, aun me marca como nulo el get_ result, a pesar de cambiarlo $sqlMedida->bindParam("s",$idVariedad);

Comment: puedes mostrarme como quedo tu código

Comment: $sqlMedida = $conexion->prepare("Select Medida from siat.medida where Variedad = :Variedad;");
$sqlMedida->bindParam(':Variedad',$idVariedad,PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
$sqlMedida->execute();
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo yo lo haría así, y accedes a tu dato de la forma: $valor['NombreDeColumnaEnDB'], tu consulta tiene una estructura un poco rara, si en el array no llega nada, revisa si tu consulta hace algo desde la consola de MySQL. Adicionalmente te dejo la documentacion de la funcion BindParam: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$idVariedad = "ALIBABA";

$sqlMedida = $conexion->prepare("Select Medida from siat.medida where Variedad = ?");
$sqlMedida->bindParam(1,$idVariedad);
$sqlMedida->execute();
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch();
```

Comment: gracias, ya consulte  la documentación que no conocía, me ayudo mucho., quedo de esta forma.
$sqlMedida = $conexion->prepare("Select Medida from siat.medida where Variedad = :Variedad;");
$sqlMedida->bindParam(':Variedad',$idVariedad,PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
$sqlMedida->execute();
$valor = $sqlMedida->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Comment: Con gusto, espero que te sirva Bro :)